# Json attribute is reachable in only Developer Console

Tags: javascript, html

thank you all for your time in reading this. I have been pulling out my hair trying to figure out why this does not work.

I am trying to reach a JSON attribute, but for some reason it only works in the developer console?

```
ID = 3039; oAuthToken = UStKiYs52uqHznMQNrbORyAAEcDH51kHF4;
fetch(`https://us.api.blizzard.com/data/wow/item/${ID}?namespace=static-us&locale=en_US&access_token=${oAuthToken}`)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => responseFromFetch = data)
            .then(newData => console.log(newData.preview_item.stats[0].display.display_string))
```

This, as expected returns the attribute I am looking for, "+16 Agility"

However, when I try to access this attribute in the following context, it is giving me the error: "Cannot read property '0' of undefined".

```
function getToolTipID() {
        let ID;
        let ID2;
        ID = (event.currentTarget.children[5].innerText.replace("ID: ", ""));
        ID2 = (event.currentTarget);
            console.log(ID);
            fetch(`https://us.api.blizzard.com/data/wow/item/${ID}?namespace=static-us&locale=en_US&access_token=${oAuthToken}`)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then((user) => {
                console.log(user.inventory_type);
                let lineContent;
                let statsArray; 
                try {
                    statsArray = user.preview_item.stats[0].display.display_string
                    console.log(statsArray)
                } catch (error) {
                    console.log(error)
                }
                console.table(statsArray)
                const lines = [
                    `${user.name}`,
                    `${user.preview_item.level.value}`,
                   /* `${user.preview_item.binding.name}`, */
                    `${user.inventory_type.name}`,
                    `${user.item_subclass.name}`,
                    `${user.preview_item.weapon.damage.display_string}`,
                    `${user.preview_item.weapon.attack_speed.display_string}`,
                    `${user.preview_item.weapon.dps.display_string}`,
                /* ACCESSING VALUE HERE */ `${user.preview_item.stats[0].display.display_string}`, */
                    `${user.preview_item.durability.display_string}`,
                    `${user.required_level}`,
                    `${user.sell_price}`
                ] 
                lineContent = user.inventory_type.name;
                let node = document.createElement('tr');
                node.innerHTML = lines;
                
                document.getElementById("toolTipDisplay").appendChild(node);
            }); 

    }
```

Is there something wrong with a dependency?

One reason that this is so weird, is that the the path I used on line 15, I got from the json response in the console, I right clicked it to get the property path.

In case it is helpful, I included a screenshot of the JSON response.

[image: JSON]

Comment: This could be user error like misreading which lines are logging where. The output you show us doesn't include a table or the statsArray log. Or maybe you've filtered out error logging in the chrome debugger. If a key exists in one place it won't magically go away in another place unless someone modifies the object, which no one has.

Comment: Thank you Andy, but I've double-triple-checked, and I copy pasted the object path from the developer console, it is the same in both snippets. There has to be something else going on :(

Comment: You should log what `user` is before `const lines` and inspect it there